# Meaning of prepended plus sign in javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

what is the effect of the '+' in the following?

```
var result = jQuery.trim(this.html2val(this.getValueJelement()[0].innerHTML));
    result = +result.replace(/[^\d\.-]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is basically a sneaky way of coercing the right-hand operand into a numeric value.  E.g.,

```
> +"42"
42
```

Answer (score 2):

It converts the operand to a number. In other words, it's basically the same as saying `result = parseFloat(result)`.

Comment: actually, `+something` is more similar to `Number(something)` than to `parseFloat(something)`, as using the `Number` global object internally calls the `ToNumber()` function that has a different set of rules to convert other types, whereas `parseFloat(something)` transforms the argument to a string and uses another set of rules to convert it to a number. A simple demonstration would be converting the `"12.3a"` value: `parseFloat("12.3a") -> 12.3; +'12.3a' -> NaN; Number('12.3a') -> NaN`

Answer (score 1):

`+a` is the [fastest way](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/type-conversion/#tcNumber) for converting `a` to number.